# Django How to work with MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django

**form.py**:

```
CHECKBOX_CHOICES = (
         ('Value1','Value1'),
         ('Value2','Value2'),
)

class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, 
                                    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
                                    choices=CHECKBOX_CHOICES,)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        u = self.instance.user
        u.interest = self.cleaned_data['interest']
        u.save()
        profile = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        return profile
```

it saves in db as `[u'value1', u'value2']`

Now, How can I only render in my template to show as string like value1, value2 without [u' '] or is there a better way to save the value as a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
u.interest = u','.join(self.cleaned_data['interest'])
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but its still saving [u'value1', u'value2'] into the database.

Comment: I'm guessing I am not saving the value correctly into the database because when I iterate over them, I get single letters. With my poor programming knowledge, I know it is just saving an unicode string, and not an array. Does anyone knows how to save it correctly into the database?

Comment: solved by doing ast.literal_eval on view. and iterate with template.